# Why does the amount of memory allocated to Spark driver / executor differ than what I pass from spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This seems like a pretty simple question, but I'm confused why there is a mismatch between the amount of memory I pass into my `spark-submit` job, and the amount of memory that Spark is actually using. For instance, on my local machine (a MacBook Pro with 16GB memory running macOS), I pass the following into my parameters:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 12G --executor-memory 12G my_spark_script.py
```

But when I look into my SparkUI at `http://localhost:4040/executors/`, I see the following (notice how there's only **6.7GB** memory available):
[image]
I clearly understand that not ALL of my 16GB local machine memory is available to any process, but is there a way I can calculate how much memory I'm actually allocated prior to running my Spark job? The reason for this is ultimately because I continually get `OutOfMemoryError`s, even despite allocating a lot of GBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that on heap memory is not the same as storage memory. As explained in the [Memory Management Overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview)

> Memory usage in Spark largely falls under one of two categories: execution and storage.

and only a fraction of unified memory is used for storage  (default 0.6).

Additionally it looks like you use development `local` mode where executor memory is not used at all.